# In flutter how to add wallpaper image?

Tags: flutter

I traying so many time but i cant add app background image, can someone tell me how to add picture in flutter in android studio

i am traying so many time but i cant add background image in flutter, some tell me about my issue please?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Stack(
        // 1 Use stack
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
              child: Image.network(
            'https://picsum.photos/id/237/1080/1920',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          )), // image as wallpaper
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor:
                  Colors.transparent, // bg color as transparent for scaffold
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text('Foo'),
                backgroundColor:
                    Colors.transparent, // bg color as transparent for app bar
                elevation: 0, // elevation as 0
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```